# Use relative address (0, 0) by default

Tags: vba, excel

I'm typing a lot of `Range.Cells().Address(0,0)` in my code to populate worksheet with logic-intensive formulas, so my code becomes quite long.

Is there any setting (something like `Application.UseRelativeAddress = True`) that will make Excel to treat simple `Range.Cells().Address` as a Relative address by default?

*I know, it won't save me too much space, but my inner perfectionist can't deal with this zeros in each cell-reference :)*

Comment: No, but you could write your own function.

Comment: @Rory - nice catch! However, actually my code is like
`With wsh
           .Cells().Address(0, 0)
End with`

So, how could I access object under With-statement from within my function? Only pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, as a parameter.